Adverb of adjectives ending in ed
I am trying to find the adverb of some adjectives ending in ed, which usually follow the pattern of having the ly suffix, but I couldn't find them in dictionaries mainly.

enhanced --> enhancedly
simulated --> simulatedly

Are these adverbs correct? If yes, is the reason I could not find them that they are just not common?

What does this have to do with BRITISH English?

Wiktionary carries the largest number of headwords of any of the English dictionaries, and is among the first to endorse neologisms. If you can't find a candidate (even one formed by a regular derivational process) you may come across as highfalutin'/pompous, facetious, or ludicrous if you yourself use it, especially without scare-quotes. Usually better to find a workaround, especially in formal contexts. // Finding the candidate being used in respectable articles is, however, an encouraging sign. << Enhancedly-solubilized beta-hydroxy acids and higher >> [Google Patents]

and << if a holo‐simulation rabies virus “simulatedly” invades >> [Justin B Rye] //  << ... There was the odd moment of wondering whether the singing was authentically ragged or simulatedly so >> [Waterbeach Theatre Company: Hilary Sage reviews Chorus of Disapproval]

As a general rule, you don't want to stop all readers in their tracks while they process one word and you distract them from understanding your whole meaning.

@Yosef I respond concurredly.

@EdwinAshworth And I return the favor with your hysterical suggestion of "highfalutin'/pompous, facetious, or ludicrous."

Supposedly there's a common word that follows this pattern.

@Barmar: Allegedly that is true, but some people may want to see examples.

grep 'edly$' /usr/share/dict/words finds 773 words. Most of them are not likely to be used much, but assuredly you'll use some of them.

Chiming in belatedly here....
